# get bits from an unsigned long in C

Tags: c

I want to get n bits from an unsigned long. 
I have this function for unsigned and I really can't put it to unsigned long, been through this for hours, please help me.

```
unsigned long getbits(unsigned long x, int p, int n){

    return (x >> (p - n + 1)) & ~(~0 << n);
}


int main() {

    printf("getbits(0x12341234abcdabcd, 31,4): 0x%016lu\n", getbits(0x12341234abcdabcd, 63, 40));
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 0x0000000000000171 instead of 0x0012341234abcdab

Comment: Break down each step and put intermediate result in variables. Inspect variables to see if they are what you think they should be. Finally perform last calculation and return result.

Comment: ...and check precedence of operators.

Comment: How does the output differ from what you expect?

Comment: The output of the example (without the unsigned long parts in getbits) is 0x0000001 but if i use the unsigned long and use 16 bytes instead of 8, i don't get what I want and I don't understand why

Comment: Please include the _incorrect_ output as well.

Comment: Again, what output do you get and what output do you expect?  Also, be sure that the code posted is the code that *isn't* working, not the code that *is* working.

Comment: What variable type do you suppose `~0` is? How many bits will be set?

Comment: I think as many as n

Comment: I meant, how many bits will be set in the value of `~0` itself? What *type* is the result of `~0` ? Is it `int`  or `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`? What is the output of this: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof (~0));` ?

Comment: @WeatherVane it's 4.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 bugs in your code:

- In function `getbits` you need to use `0UL` instead of `0`,
  because `~0` is `0xFFFFFFFF`, but `~0UL` is `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFUL`.
- In your `printf` call you need to use `%016lx` instead of `%016lu`,
  because you want hexadecimal output instead of decimal  output.

Comment: I suggest `0UL` because you should not left shift a signed integer (even though it may be OK in this particular case), and to match the working type.

Answer (score 1):

In this expression

```
(~0 << n)
```

The value `0` is of type `int`.

If you want to work with the larger type, you will need

```
(~0ul << n)
```

Comment: The output is exactly the same. Not sure if that's the problem, but i'm not seeing it as well

Comment: Well, what size is `unsigned long` on your system? The question suggests it is 64 bit, but it might be only 32.